# Image Identifiers and List of Images with pandoc?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I have a text written in markdown (with pandoc extensions) with several image-references. Now I need to build a table or list with these images with a reference to the page they appear on. Just listing the captions and the page would be sufficient. Is there any possibility to do this with pandoc in an easy way, that is without using raw latex commands in the markdown-file?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody posted a workaround for this, using pandocs implementation of a numbered example list:
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/904

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to SU! Link-only posts are considered a no-no due to possible future link-rot.  Please include pertinent information directly in your answer, and then use the link to site the source.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your (or a copy of your) default.latex template and insert
**\listoffigures** right before **\end{document}**

All PDFs created with that template will include a latex-generated list of figures with figure number, title and page number. Just make sure your images are properly embedded in figure environments by adding a caption to each.